# How much free space does fsck need to rebuild the catalog file?

Tags: macos, fsck

I am in single-user mode, running `fsck -fy`.

It attempts to rebuild the catalog file and exits with a status of `-34`, complaining of a `disk full error`.

How much free space does the disk need to have for `fsck` to do its work?  Right now it has over 150 GB free, which is about 25% of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

To rebuild the catalog you need continuous space. Obviously, you do not have enough.